# Postman "Environment quick look" not displaying Globals variables

Tags: variables, postman, environment, persist, global

I'm new to Postman and am having an issue with the "Environment quick look" not displaying any Globals variables. Other members of my team have looked at this and they can't understand why I'm experiencing this issue and they are not.

[image]

I have the latest version of Postman installed (v6.0.9 - the same version as other team members that don't have the problem).

I also have ran the same tests collection that was created by another team member and checked the "Persist Variables" checkbox before the test run but to no avail.

[image]

I have also attempted to uninstall and reinstall my instance of the Windows x64 version of Postman but this made no difference. I'm not sure this uninstall worked fully as the fresh install remembered the certificate that I required for the external API that we are characterising.

Other team members are seeing the Globals variables like so:
[image]

Has anybody else come across this strange behavior and have a solution?

Comment: Have you added the environment and global variables in your postman interface earlier. Because first you have to add the environment and global variables

Comment: Yes. The collection that I am running has 400 tests and has many environment and global variables that other team members can see when they run on their machines.

Comment: Try postman.setEnvironmentVariable and postman.setGlobalVariable as defined here http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/02/20/using-variables-inside-postman-and-collection-runner/. It may help

Comment: We are setting many Global Variables within "Pre-request Script" using the new postman syntax e.g. `pm.globals.set("Id", Id);` Also, as mentioned previously other team members are seeing these global variables show up

Answer (score 0):

What entries do you have in your `Manage Environment` settings? (Click on the cogwheel to access it.)

Comment: I don't have any entries here but other team members do.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get around this issue (which I still don't why it is occurring) is the following:

- I opened Manage Environment
- I clicked the Import button
- I browsed to a JSON file that was saved off by a member of the team that could see the Globals variables (who used the Download as JSON option)
- Quick look now displayed and remembered the Globals variables

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem using the Postman web interface via Chrome on a Mac. Closing the browser window and signing in anew solved it for me.